# Grails: use Spock to test template rendering

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I use Spock to test an action of a controller as below:

code in controller:

```
def milestoneChange() {
    Milestones selectedMilestone = dataQueryService.getMilestone(params.id)
    Tasks[] tasksList = dataQueryService.getTasksList(params.id)
    List enumerateNameList = dataQueryService.getEnumerateNameList()

    render(template: 'milestoneSummary', model: [selectedMilestone: selectedMilestone, tasksList: tasksList, enumerateNameList: enumerateNameList, selectedMilestoneID: params.id])
}
```

code in test:

```
    @TestFor(MilestonesMgtController)
class MilestonesMgtControllerSpec extends Specification {
void "change the milestone"() {
    when:
    views['/milestonesMgt/_milestoneSummary.gsp'] = "test"
    controller.params.id = 'Late Stage Review'
    controller.milestoneChange()

    then:
    controller.response.text == 'test'
}
```

}

Because the content of the _milestoneSummary.gsp is very long, I use the approach mentioned in both Grails documentation and http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/grails-goodness-unit-testing-render-templates-from-controller.html which is using views['/milestonesMgt/_milestoneSummary.gsp'] to mock the template. However, the response is still the original long content? Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? Thanks very much!!!

BTW when using params/response/model, I have to use controller.xxx, but I see the sample code in documentation use params/response/model directly, do you know why?

I am using Grails 2.3.8

the project link http://github.com/jackyying1130/MMS 
the test is located in MMS/test/integration/phdmilestonemanagementsystem/MilestonesMgtControllerSpec.gr‌​oovy

Comment: This works as expected. Clean your app once to be on the safer side although it should not matter.

Comment: not working after clean. I suspect it doesn't catch the template path: /milestonesMgt/_milestoneSummary.gsp.

Comment: is groovyPages['/sample/_header.gsp'] working instead of views[...]? as mentioned in the article?

Comment: groovyPages doesn't work either

Comment: Share a sample app in github show casing this issue.

Comment: @dmahapatro shared, please check https://github.com/jackyying1130/MMS  the test is located in MMS/test/integration/phdmilestonemanagementsystem/MilestonesMgtControllerSpec.groovy

Comment: This should be a unit spec instead of an integration spec. Just move the file to test/unit and change the content as you have in question, use views[..], everything would pass. - Thumb typed.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro , I believe this should be the problem. I turn to use integration test from unit test because the first test cannot run properly under unit test due to the involvement of services in the controller. I think I should go back to unit test and try to figure out how to deal with service.